# 2-month paid internship visa for Germany

Tags: germany

I am Tunisian, and reside in Tunisia. I do not hold any type of visa or work permit.

I am spending a two-month internship in Germany as part of my Engineering curriculum. Do I need a ZAV document for the visa?

Update: a zav document is a consent letter from the German labor agencency for foreigners to work in Germany

Comment: What is ZAV document?

Comment: I updated a description of the document

Answer (score 0):

No. ZAV deals with foreigners who are looking for a job in Germany or with Germans who are looking for a job abroad. You are not in any of these two categories. A letter from the company where you'll have your internship must be enough.